# how to config CNMI to receive delivary message?

Tags: gsm, modem

I have a d-link gsm modem (DWM-156) and i want to config CNMI to receive delivery reports after sending a text message.

The support CNMI mode on my modem returns:

```
+CNMI: (0-3), (0-3), (0,2,3), (0,1), (0,1)
```

The default mode returns:

```
+CNMI: 2, 1, 0, 0, 1
```

When i send a message i do not receive a delivery report.

I tried changing my CNMI to

```
        2, 1, 2, 1, 0
```

but my sim card and d-link modem storage still have not stored any messages.

This process has worked on my (Huawei) modem that had this CNMI:

```
"AT+CNMI=2,1,2,2,0"
```

I tested these CNMI configs on my D-Link modem but it did not works

```
2, 1, 0, 0, 1
2, 1, 0, 1, 1
2, 1, 2, 0, 1
2, 1, 1, 1, 1
2, 1, 3, 0, 1
2, 1, 3, 1, 1
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? Currently i am doing the same thing, trying to get the sms status report, by settings at+cnmi=2,2,0,1,0 i manage to get the sms status. With this code i manage to get the status report  message  but the status report only appears on the telnet console. I am currently trying to figure it out ou to save the satus report on de memory of the sim.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the gsm modem i am currently using is a portech mv374...there might be some diferences on the parameters when setting the cnmi command. you can check if is possible to run this comand by doing at+cnmi=? and check the possible values for each parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but..
I am using `AT+CSMS=1;+CNMI=2,1,0,1,1`, have tried this on some Telit modems.

I get the *SMS-STATUS-REPORT* directly over the serial port, it isn't stored as such in the modem. There is no reference to a memory storage in the message, only the length of the *PDU*.
When I get the report it looks like this :

```
+CDS: 24

<pdu>
```

Also, when I receive a SMS-STATUS-REPORT I need to send ACKnowledge to the modem/mobile network using the `AT+CNMA` command.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0
```